# how to specify quotes when using sql query in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, reactive, rsqlite

I'm trying to create a simple app to show how to write sql queries: users can type in their full sql queries and see the results.

Unfortunately I can't get the app to work if i add a string to the query, e.g. `select * from iris where Species = 'setosa'`

This brings the `error: unrecognized token: "'"`

Here's a repex:

```
library(shiny)
library(RSQLite)

db_example <- RSQLite::datasetsDb()

# check this works outside of shiny:
#dbGetQuery(db_example, "SELECT * FROM iris WHERE Species = 'setosa' ; ")

ui<- fluidPage(
  textInput(inputId = "sql_query",
            label = "write your sql query:"),
  actionButton(inputId = "submit", label = "Run"),
  tableOutput(outputId = "my_table")

)

server <- function(input,output) {

  my_result <- eventReactive(input$submit, {

    dbGetQuery(db_example,
               input$sql_query
               )

  })

  output$my_table <- renderTable({
    my_result()
  })

}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

It works fine for just `select * from iris` but if you try adding a string condition such as 
`select * from iris where Species = 'setosa'` it throws an error, even though the same syntax works fine outside of Shiny.

I've tried various syntax to get the quoting to work as expected with no luck (including escaping with )... Any ideas how this should be done?

Here's my session details:

R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.6

> packageVersion("shiny")
>   [1] ‘1.3.2’
>   packageVersion("RSQLite")
>   [1] ‘2.1.1’

UPDATE: This seems to be a platform specific issue as i got the same code to work fine on our server... so this issue on macOS Mojave 10.14.6  remains a bit of a mystery...

Comment: I ran your code on my laptop and it works fine for me. What versions of R, shiny and RSQLite are you using?

Comment: You can easily escape the quotes `"SELECT * FROM iris WHERE Species = \'setosa\' ; "`

Comment: @PorkChop i had tried that but no it doesn't work, not in the context of a reactive object in a shiny app.

Comment: @kluu how odd.. i'm using shiny 1.3.2 and RSQLite 2.1.1. with R 3.6.1. on a mac

Comment: Print this first `print(noquote(input$sql_query))`

Comment: @PorkChop no that's even worse: even a query with no string doesn't work now :)

Comment: might be the parsing of `RSQLite`, im using `odbc` and `dbi` myself